# How close I am to getting Inquisitive badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was checking my user profile on stack exchange and found this feature very useful (3/5 says almost whole story).

[image]

But this feature is not yet available on stack overflow website. And I hope it will take sometime before integration of these set of features with stack overflow.

Till then, is there any way I can get to know, how close I am to getting **Inquisitive** badge on stack overflow?